# Loopback ctx.instance vs ctx.data

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I am not able to understand the difference between
`Ctx.instance` and  `Ctx.data` in loopback 'before save ' callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is described in our documentation, see [Operation hooks >> before save](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#before-save). Cross-posting the relevant content here:

> Depending on which method triggered this hook, the context will have one of the following sets of properties:
>
> - Full save of a single model
>
>   - (...)
>   - `instance` - the model instance to be saved. The value is an instance of Model class.
> - Partial update of possibly multiple models
>
>   - (...)
>   - `data` - the (partial) data to apply during the update
>   - `currentInstance` - the affected instance.

When you call `Customer.create({/*...*/})`, the hook is invoked with `ctx.instance` set to the instance of your model with all properties populated from the object passed to `create()`:

```
{
  name: 'Miroslav',
  isPreferred: false,
  // etc.
}
```

When you call `customer.patchAttributes({isPreferred: true})`, the hook is invoked with `ctx.data` containing only the properties provided to `patchAttributes()`.

```
{
  isPreferred: true
}
```

You can learn more in the source code, see [`loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/master/lib/dao.js).